# Create a temp table with duplicate column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a temp table in SQL Server Management Studio 18 from which I can query. It uses a pre-existing query that already runs, and creates a file.

This is a QA mirror of a production database at a massive company, and the number of columns is quite large: about 200. It needs to be this way, as all of the data is necessary. Several of the column names are duplicates, as the file is parsed in a way that formats it on the receiving end.

I also don't have access to simply upload the file into a QA database and query it, and so I have to make a temp table. Is there any way to simply allow/force duplicate columns when making a temp table using:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM (subquery)
```

?

Comment: No, column names in a table must be unique - you must select the columns by name and provide an alias if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure how that query relates to anything you talk about; a subquery (or object) can't have multiple columns with the same name. If you have a subquery you're getting the data from it *cannot* have 2 columns with the same name defined.

Comment: Presumably, as you're talking about a file, you're using an ETL process to get that data into SQL Server, so that process will be giving those columns with the same name diffrwnr tnames in the destination table. If not then how are you ending up with *some thing* that has multiple columns with the same name?

Comment: @ThomA a query can return a resultset with duplicate column names, you just cannot have a table with duplicate column names, [https://dbfiddle.uk/FvXLVQac](https://dbfiddle.uk/FvXLVQac)

Comment: The final dataset returned by a query can, a *subquery* (which I explicitly mentioned) can't, @Stu .

Comment: I presume the OP using the term *sub*query here just simply means "query" as otherwise yes, you're right of course.

Comment: @ThomA, yes, it's part of an ETL process that is extracting data from multiple tables and sending it as a .txt file with multiple fields that are identical, and is then parsed on the receiving end in order. I've been tasked with testing whether the correct data appears and am running into difficulties with querying the results of the ETL process.

Comment: If you know the name of the columns, how many minutes does it take to copy it as a list, append the table names/alias and then replace the eventual duplicates

Comment: Also an fyi, you can drag/drop tables from object explorer onto a query window and get the column names, or 3rd-party tools like SQLPrompt can populate a query with column text from tables or expressions etc to make your life easier.

Comment: Even ssms can generate a crude column name list, select first row, right click and choose copy with headers

Comment: @Stu, the amount of time it will take to individually label the hundreds of fields from the several different aliased tables used in this query through multiple joins will take quite a while. Hence why I asked if there was a way to save myself a few hours of manual work. And I have no access to third party tools because of security restrictions on our devices and work environment.

Comment: @siggemannen, doesn't help much when there are hundreds of fields that come from several joins in the query that I'm trying to make into a temp table, and the original SELECT is *. I didn't ask this question because I was trying to save a couple of minutes.

Comment: @thesmiter1 depending on the actual query in question you could use the output of [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: You have a query that looks like select * from table1 inner join table2 ... * works table by table, so i don't get the problem of getting all columns from table1, appending it with alias and then moving on, if you have some table without duplicates, a t.* might work too

Comment: You don't have to *alias* hundreds of them, just the duplicates. Though if you need hundreds of columns I'd question that you're doing it wrong; it's highly unlikely you need a dataset with hundreds of columns returned.

Comment: Though, in truth, you've probably spent more time here, telling us that'll take too much time than it would have taken to write the query and alias the appropriate columns. At most it would have likely been 10 minutes work for a `SELECT *` with no expressions.

Comment: If the subquery is producing duplicate column names just alias them, i.e.: `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM (subquery) Q(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)`. Sometimes you just have to do the work.